# Detect browser closed event only

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

Ho do I detect Browser close event only, ie. I have a web application which allows any user to be signed in only once. So if the user by mistake or purposely closes the browser my application does not allow it to login again as the flag which was being set during logging in was not cleared when user closes the browser. So I would like to detect closing of the browser and log him off if its detected.

I tried `onbeforeunload`, but this also fired when page is being redirected or browser url is changed. Is there a way by which I can only track browser closing or Browser URL change?

Comment: There is no such event. Regrading your 'login out' logic, you could set some logic using `sessionStorage` client side maybe but usually, this has been to be handled server side